# import only some parts of a module, but list those parts as strings

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, python-import

This question was marked as [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718885/import-module-from-string-variable). However the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718885/import-module-from-string-variable) questions deals with modules while my question is asking for how to import parts of module.

I know that I can `import` certain portions of the module by using `from mymodule import myfunction`. What if want to import several things, but I need to list them as strings. For example:

```
import_things = ['thing1', 'thing2', 'thing2']
from mymodule import import_things
```

I did ask [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40476546/list-modules-as-strings-and-import-them), but it looks like I need to use the trick (if there is one) above for my code as well.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import importlib

base_module = importlib.import_module('mymodule')
imported_things = {thing: getattr(base_module, thing) for thing in import_things}

imported_things['thing1']() # Function call
```

If you want to be able to use the things which have been imported globally, then do:

```
globals().update(imported_things)
thing1() # function call
```

To remove the imports, you can do

```
del thing1
```

or

```
del globals()['thing1']
```

Another useful operation you can do is to [`reload`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) a module

Comment: This imports modules from the package. I need the ability to import methods and classes from the module.

Comment: Another question. How would I unimport them? Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @flashburn see comment

Comment: This is not exactly what I'm looking for. And I don't know if it is possible in `python` at all. I'm would like to unload those things from memory and not reload them. Is it possible?

Comment: @flashburn I'm not sure I'm following you. If you `del` something in python, all references to it become invalid. Maybe you need to ask a different question

Comment: No I think I got.